# How to add a custom function to a wordpress site theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want to add a custom function to my wordpress site functions.php file like this :

```
//Test adding basic REST API custom endpoint.
/**
 * Grab latest post title by an author!
 *
 * @param array $data Options for the function.
 * @return string|null Post title for the latest,  * or null if none.
 */
function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'author' => $data['id'],
    ) );

    if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    return $posts[0]->post_title;
}


add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'walden/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ) );
} );
```

But wherever I paste this code it causes the whole functions to fail and all rest api links give me error .

Exactly where I should paste this piece of code in functions.php so it won't ruin all the other functions ?

Comment: It should work putting it in functions.php. If it doesn't then it's the code that's broken, not the placement. If you explain what the above code suppose to do, when it suppose to do it and what actually happens (including what errors you get), we might be able to help.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I want to add  a custom rest api to my wordpress site thanks for help

Comment: You need to give us more details. We need to know exactly what happens and what that code is suppose to actually do, what do you expect to happen when you run it and what does currently happen? Edit the question to include that info (in _details_)

Answer (score 0):

As of WordPress 5.5, if a permission_callback is not provided, the REST API will issue a _doing_it_wrong notice.

```
<?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'walden/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
  ) );
} );
```

I guess your register_rest_route function is missing `permission_callback` param.

It would be better if you give more informations about the error.